# Excel (VBA, Userform) How can I extra the data from Listbox to a specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

Here is what I have so far, there is only one column of data, and I want to extract it and write it down in a specific cell (like: sheet14.cells(45,2).value)

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you mean is you want to **extract** data from a ListBox to a specific cell

Here is my answer

Inside the code of the userform put a button for the function

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i 'to store the item of the list
    Dim j 'Just a counter
    j = 0 'Ini the counter
    For Each i In Me.ListBox1.List 'Ini the for loop
        j = j + 1 'Add one to the counter
        Cells(j, 4).Value = i 'here is the thing. 
        'In the cell(row = j, column = 4 = D) put the value: i = the item of the list
        'This take all the items of the list, inside the combobox. 
    Next i 'Next one please! 
End Sub
```

**Edit #1**

Reading (aging) yous question, see that you want to write the list in a sheet that is not active... well here goes!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i 'to store the item of the list
    Dim j 'Just a counter
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'the var for the sheet you want
    Set sht = Sheets("S")
    'the name of the sheet I want is "S", stored inside the var sht
    j = 0 'Ini the counter
    For Each i In Me.ListBox1.List 'Ini the for loop
        j = j + 1 'Add one to the counter
        sht.Cells(j, 4).Value = i 'here is the thing.
        'In the cell(row = j, column = 4 = D)
        'put the value: i = the item of the list
        'This take all the items of the list, inside the combobox.
    Next i 'Next one please!
End Sub
```

**Edit#2**

Now you can use it in a ListBox. And the change is pretty simple, just erase the ComboBox1 and write "ListBox1", it is functional with that two controls.

**Edit #3**

With this code you put everything inside a single cell

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i 'to store the item of the list
    Dim j 'Just a counter
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'the var for the sheet you want
    Set sht = Sheets("S")
    'the name of the sheet I want is "S", stored inside the var sht
    j = 0 'Ini the counter
    For Each i In Me.ListBox1.List 'Ini the for loop
        j = j + 1 'Add one to the counter
        sht.Cells(1, 4).Value = sht.Cells(1, 4).Value & Chr(10) & i
        'here is the thing.
        'In the cell(row = 1, column = 4 = D)
        'put the value: i = the item of the list
        'besides the others values.
        'Everything inside a single cell
        'This take all the items of the list, inside the combobox.
    Next i 'Next one please!
End Sub
```

Tell me if you need some improvement.

Comment: its is a listbox, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Check my Edit #2, I made the change, and take note that the code is functional for the comboBox and the ListBox.

Comment: And change is very straightforward, it was enough to look at the properties of both controls and see what changes needed to be made. If you want something more documentation about the controls in question you can look that can be done in VBA with those controls. Or just write the name of the control and then point to the list of available properties.